# Django model that is easily expandable

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model, call it A, implemented in Django.

I would like to store some statistics, call them x, y and z, about A that are computationally intensive within A (I can't compute them on the fly efficiently).

However, I would also like to add new statistics, say w, p and q, down the road. The statistics will be integers or floats.

I'd like to write A store that it stores x, y. z today, and allows me to add w, p, q, ... later without having to change the model. How can I implement A effectively?

Note: I'm using Django 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate table called Statistics with the attributes statistic_name, value and foreignkey_Amodel.